# Imitate the gradient style of outlook 2007

Tags: wpf, outlook

Anyone here who has the style of the Outlook 2007 'gradient' like in the following screenshot (the container where the 'Deleted Items' is placed'):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could simply be a TextBox whose background is styled as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="Deleted Items" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#0080FF" Height="20" Width="150">
    <TextBox.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5 0" EndPoint="0.5 1">
            <GradientStop Color="#EFF8FB" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#A9E2F3" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

This could of course become a Style and placed int the UserControl.Resources, Page.Resources or Window.Resources section of your view.